# Jetlang limit messages in MemoryChannel

Tags: java, concurrency

Is there a well-defined way in Jetlang to limit the number of messages that can be sent on a particular channel?

I have an actor which is subscribed to a MemoryChannel. There is a possibility that it can receive more requests/sec than it can process so eventually this could lead to an OutOfMemory exception.

Thanks and Regards,
Abraham Menacherry.

Comment: Have you tried asking the jetlang developers group ? http://groups.google.com/group/jetlang-dev?pli=1

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have cross posted it there. The list seems to be spammed though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike Rettig was kind enough to answer this on the jetlang dev group. Here is the [link](http://groups.google.com/group/jetlang-dev/browse_thread/thread/1949e9d3fc0b783d)

This requirement was not met by Jetlang out of the box, so Mike made a change to the Jetlang internal classes for it.